# Passing char array to a function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, parameter-passing, function-call

Passing an array to a function, do it need to use `&`?

In below example Case 1 or Case 2, which one is good ?

```
#define IP_ADDR_LEN  4 
char ip[4]={192,168,205,1};
char PeerIP[4];
int main()
{
   memcpy(PeerIP,ip,IP_ADDR_LEN)

   testip(PeerIP);   /* Case 1 */

   testip(&PeerIP);   /*Case 2*/
}

int testip(char *ip)
{
  /* IP check */

}
```

Comment: Note that you should declare (or define) `testip()` before you call it.  If you do that, the compiler will be able to tell you that the `testip(&PeerIP);` call is passing the wrong type to the function — it's an `int (*)[4]` and not an `int *` that is being passed.  Find out how to make your compiler insist on functions being defined or declared before being used, with strict prototypes, and then use it.

Answer (score 2):

The first one.

```
  testip(PeerIP);
```

is the right way to do it, as an array name will decay to a pointer to the first element of the array, which matches the expected type for the called function parameter.

To elaborate, in your code, `testip()` expects an argument of type `char *` and by calling it like `testip(PeerIP);` you are passing a `char *`, so no issues.

In case you use the `&PeerIP`, the type will be [`char (*) [4]`] pointer to array, **not** pointer to the first element of the array [`char *`] and they are different type.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.3.2.1, *Lvalues, arrays, and function designators*, (*emphasis mine*)

> **Except when it is** the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the `_Alignof` operator, or **the
>   unary `&` operator**, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, **an expression that has
>   type *‘‘array of type’’* is converted to an expression with type *‘‘pointer to type’’* that points
>   to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue**. [...]

Comment: Different type, but both point to the same address. Only pointer arithmetic will differ.

Comment: @StoryTeller right, but still the __later would be wrong__. Just because they point to same address doe not mean the expressions are interchangeable. Types matter. :)

Comment: They do indeed matter very much. I just had my c++ background pop up. Where casting pointers to array references is done "correctly" thanks to that fact :)